# Question about the それに

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the meaning of それに in the following passage(second one). Does it means something like "To that, after supressing this intense sleepiness, Taito said." So, this それに refers to the invitation of his friends, same as the first one?

> 「おお、じゃ一緒にやろうよ。これ四人プレイできるから人数が多いほうが楽しい」
>
> と誘ってくれて。
>
> それに(1st)大兎は、ゲームに参加して、今日は遥のミーティングが終わるのを待とうかなぁ、とかも、考えたが。
>
> しかし。
>
> 「・・・・・・」
>
> しかしそこでまた、あくびが出た。そして強烈な眠気が頭のなかに広がって、まるで寝ろ、寝ろ、寝ろといわれているようで。
>
> **それに**(2nd)。その、強烈な眠気を噛み殺すようにしてから、大兎は言った。

Comment: Uncommon sentence endings and a distracting use of periods --- all the way.

Comment: I'm just curious. Where does this passage come from? Narration of an anime?

Comment: @kmk From the light novel, いつか天魔の黒ウサギ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, それに means:

1. besides, in addition, moreover
2. (literally) to it/that, for it/that, against it/that

I think most native speakers instantly try to interpret this second それに in the first sense. So probably this can be translated as "Besides."

Something must be omitted after it, but what's omitted cannot be determined, as far as I can see in this quoted text. If Taito is worried about something not mentioned here, then that's it (e.g. "Besides (... he remembered he really has to leave here in 30 minutes)).

But anyway, as @l'électeur indicated, this text is awkward and far from what I expect in an ordinary novel. Apparently the author [intentionally chose this clumsy style](http://www.amazon.co.jp/review/R1FPO4E6T39TXV/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=4829133473&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=465392&store=books), and he tends to [repeat words meaninglessly](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/hobo_king/touch/20081204/1228399418). So this それに may be nothing but an almost meaningless filler to add extra chaos, or simulate Taito's confusion.